# Woocommerce изображение товара формата .gif

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce 3.5.6

Если вставляю главное изображение gif его не показывает(только при наведении), я так понял потому что его обрезает и оно не работает. Как сделать если загружаю gif оно не обрезало его а остальное обрезало. 
Там используется wc_get_gallery_image_html

```
if ( $product->get_image_id() ) {
            $html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, true );
        }
```

я так и не понял как изменить его. Для дополнительных изображений так же проблема. Решение убрать обрезание в кастомизации не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот так, правда если для товара в настройках поменять размер придется и в коде менять.

**Для товара**

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html','remove_single_product_image_size',10,4);

function remove_single_product_image_size( $image_html, $attachment_id ){

 return str_replace( ['-600x600.gif','-300x300.gif','-50x50.gif'], ['.gif','.gif','.gif'], $image_html );
}
```

**Для товара в категории**

```
add_filter( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', 'filter_function_name_6177' );
function filter_function_name_6177( $size ){

$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
$image = wp_check_filetype($image);

if ($image[ext] == 'gif') {
      $size = 'full';
    } 
    return $size;
}
```